# How to Check for an empty object property in an array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In my application i am having a data which is an array of objects.if any of the object property in any of the objects in the array is empty,then the data should not be saved. consider the sample data below, how to loop through all the objects in the array and check for any empty value.in below data the third object has an empty fname propety,how to find empty object properties like that

```
var obj = [{fname:"name1",lname:"lname1"},
           {fname:"name2",lname:"name2"},
           {fname:"",lname:"name3"}
          ];
```

Comment: _"if any of the object property in any of the objects in the array is null"_ Can you provide an example of what you are trying to describe and expected result?

Comment: There's no property with `null` as its value in your example

Comment: @guest271314 null means i am referring it as a empty value.the third object fname property is empty right.i want to find out object properties like that

Comment: @codegeek `null` is not an empty `string`.

Comment: @codegeek What should occur if `"fname"` value is `""`?

Comment: @guest271314 it should find the properties has value like "" only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can get a list of all values in an object using `Object.values()`. You can use `filter()` to filter elements from an array. Combining these two you can do something like this:

You can also keep an array of all the values you don't want and then check if any of these exist in object values that you are filtering.

```js
var obj = [{fname:"name1",lname:"lname1"},
        {fname:"name2",lname:"name2"},
        {fname:"",lname:"name3"},
        {fname:null,lname:"name4"}];

var filterobj = obj.filter(function(o){
    var values = Object.values(o);
    var arr2 = ["", null]; //array of values you don't want.
    if(arr2.some(function (val) { return values.indexOf(val) >= 0; })) //checks if atleast one value of arr2 is in values.
         return false;
    else 
         return true;
});

console.log(filterobj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.reduce` to reduce the array to only the elements that have a non empty `fname`

```js
var obj = [{fname:"name1",lname:"lname1"},
        {fname:"name2",lname:"name2"},
        {fname:"",lname:"name3"},
        {fname:null,lname:"name4"}];

var goodNames = obj.reduce(function (notEmptyNames, name) { 
    if (name.fname) notEmptyNames.push(name);
    return notEmptyNames;
}, []);

console.log(goodNames);
```